# open any page inside div using window.open in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the code:

```
var flashlaunchserver="http://devonestopdigital.s3.amazonaws.com/";
```

now i am opening the new window like:

```
window.open(flashlaunchserver, "_blank",'left=0,top=0,width=1010,height=700,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,fullscreen=no,directories=no', false);
```

It is opens in new window But i want to open this window.open inside div tags.

is there any way.

Comment: I'm afraid you should use frames or iframes for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the limitations of JavaScript's XmlHttpRequest object concerning cross-domain requests, you would need to build a page scraper on your server side that is accessible through AJAX. Then you could create an AJAX request locally that would call your function.

Your function would need to scrape out the `<html>` -> `<body>` tags and the ending tags. Then the raw html could be inserted into your div with `innerHTML`. This would be a lot of work to accomplish something that would be much simpler with iframes.

**Edit:** As a side note, scraping tags out is touchy because you need to make sure you **don't** scrape out any necessary scripts, or resource includes.

Answer (score 1):

You can only load external content in an iframe:

`<iframe src="http://devonestopdigital.s3.amazonaws.com/"></iframe>`

Comment: I think, Using Iframe is not the best way because in some enviorment iFrame is not supported.

Comment: A frame is the only way to do it. An iframe is supported wide in any major browser. What kind of environment are you talking about?

Comment: how about the `object` tag or `embedded` tag?!